# Why is Android DocumentFile not restored from a File?

Tags: java, android, android-file, storage-access-framework

I know this sounds strange. I am seeking an understanding of an issue, not a solution to a problem.

Here is the code:

```
DocumentFile dfFolderFoo;
...
//dfFolderFoo is set to a valide value
...
File fFoo = new File(dfFolderFoo.getUri().toString()); 
DocumentFile dfFolderFooNew = DocumentFile.fromFile(fFoo);
//dfFolderFooNew is different from dfFolderFoo
//dfFolderFoo.listFiles() contains a dozen file while dfFolderFooNew.listFiles() contains 0.
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: No that does not work. I wonder why there is such a member fromFile()..

Comment: I have no clue.